# MySQL Create Procedure syntax issue

Tags: mysql

I'm getting a syntax error around the INSERT INTO that I cannot seem to shake out what is the issue between what fellow developers I've asked in addition to the MySQL docs. Any assistance on what might be wrong here would be greatly appreciated.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE teacher_insert(
        IN p_id int,
        IN p_dept int,
        IN p_name varchar(50),
        IN p_phone varchar(50),
        IN p_mobile varchar(50)
        )
        BEGIN
            IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE id = p_id) THEN
            BEGIN
                UPDATE teacher
                SET dept = p_dept,
                    name = p_name,
                    phone = p_phone,
                    mobile = p_mobile
                WHERE id = p_id
            END
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                INSERT INTO teacher (id,dept,name,phone,mobile)
                VALUES(p_id,p_dept,p_name,p_phone,p_mobile)
            END
        END
```

Comment: Get rid of `SET`, it doesn't belong in `INSERT`, only in `UPDATE`

Comment: If `teacher.id` is the primary key, you should be able to do this with `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...`

Comment: You don't need `BEGIN` and `END` around a single statement.

Comment: You need `;` at the end of each statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You need `;` after each statement in a procedure.
2. You don't put `SET` before the list of columns in an `INSERT`.

But you're doing lots of extra work, because you can use a single `INSERT` with `ON DUPLICATE KEY` instead of checking for the key with `IF` (assuming the `id` column is a unique key).

```
CREATE PROCEDURE teacher_insert(
    IN p_id int,
    IN p_dept int,
    IN p_name varchar(50),
    IN p_phone varchar(50),
    IN p_mobile varchar(50)
    )
INSERT INTO teacher (id,dept,name,phone,mobile)
VALUES (p_id,p_dept,p_name,p_phone,p_mobile)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    dept = VALUES(dept),
    name = VALUES(name),
    phone = VALUES(phone),
    mobile = VALUES(mobile)
;
```